# Retrieve attributes from multiple levels in XPATH

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Given XML similar to the following XML

```
<all>
<alpha a="zulu">
<bravo b="yankee" />
</alpha>
<alpha a="xray">
<charlie b="whiskey" />
</alpha>
</all>
```

Is there an XPATH query that will return this? Specifically, I'll be running this in a python project with lxml.

```
a="zulu",b="yankee"
a="xray",b="whiskey"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('input.xml')

for item in tree.xpath('//alpha/descendant-or-self::*'):
    print item.attrib
```

Output is:

```
{'a': 'zulu'}
{'b': 'yankee'}
{'a': 'xray'}
{'b': 'whiskey'}
```